# Send email to multiple addresses (using cc) from different domains

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, smtplib

I've made a little Python script that sends emails using `smtplib`.

For example, I have an email that needs to be sent to **n** users (via `To:` field), but I also need to send this email to **m** other users, via `Cc:` field.

Obviously those **n** + **m** email addresses are from different domains (@mydomain, @gmail, @hotmail, @whatever). The emails are correctly delivered to each address if I put the email addresses in the `To:` field, but the same thing doesn't happen if I put the emails in the `Cc:` field....

For example

```
FROM: me@mydomain.com 
TO: alice@mydomain.com, bob@gmail.com, mallory@hotmail.com
CC: john@mydomain.com, robert@yahoo.com, clara@gmail.com
```

note that the email is sent using a `@mydomain.com` account. The addresses in the `TO:` list correctly receive the email, while **only john@mydomain.com**, from the `CC:` list, get the email..

It seems that the `CC` field works only with *same-domain-email*... Any idea?

Anyway, this is the code:

```
msg = MIMEText(mailContent)
msg["Subject"] = "This is the subject"
msg["From"] = "me@mydomain.com"

toEmails = ["alice@mydomain.com", "bob@gmail.com", "mallory@hotmail.com"]
ccEmails = ["john@mydomain.com", "robert@yahoo.com", "clara@gmail.com"]

msg["To"] = ",".join(toEmails)
msg["Cc"] = ",".join(ccEmails)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()  
server.login("me@mydomain.com", "password")  
server.sendmail("me@mydomain.com", toEmails, msg.as_string())  
server.quit()
```

Thanks

Comment: You are connecting to google's smtp server. Did you check they have any restrictions? Try any other smtp server.

Comment: actually I'm using google's smtp because `mydomain` is a business domain created in google..

Comment: related: [`smtplib.send_message()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3e19634b396f/Lib/smtplib.py#l791) shows how other headers such as `Bcc`, `Sender`, `Resent-*` could be used with `smtplib.sendmail()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line

```
server.sendmail("me@mydomain.com", toEmails+ccEmails, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: that won't send the email via `CC`.. will only send the email to all the addresses using `TO`

Comment: did you try,MIMEText will add all details as email header, i believe based on email headers smtp will decide to send emails but you have to include all emails in sendmail

Comment: +1. @BeNdErR here's a [complete code example](https://gist.github.com/zed/9113858)